# Spring Web Service

Tags: spring-ws

I want Spring Webservice program in details. I have visited many websites , no website is providing me in proper. I want that program to be detailed and clear explained. It is better if you use any one of the Netbeans of Eclipse Ganymade IDE's

Comment: The spring webservices tutorial has all you need. http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/tutorial.html

Comment: Gobbling magic pills while a paranoid vision of ghosts chasing you down a never ending series of simply described corridors played itself out.  Wonder where the original idea came from?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at a very simplified post on how to build web services using Spring-WS[Title: Building a web service with Spring-WS] at

http://justcompiled.blogspot.com/2010/09/building-web-service-with-spring-ws.html